# Kotlin - assign value inside while to use it outside

Tags: kotlin, while-loop

I'm very new in kotlin and wanted to solve following problem with a do while:
I want to create a hash and want to check if there is the same hash stored in a key-value store as a key.
In java I would make it with a String variable which I declared outside the while. But that will only work with a var in Kotlin and I learned that it is common practise to avoid var.
My code looks as following (with var...)

```
var hash = ""
do {
    hash = createHash(longUrl)
    val optional = shortUrlRepository.findById(hash)
} while(optional.isPresent)
```

What would you say is the best way to solve this?

thank you a lot!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i played around a bit and copied the false version.
What I want to do is to create a new Hash as long the actual created one is already stored in the database.

Comment: It's common practice to avoid var when it doesn't get reassigned. If it does get reassigned then of course you use var, because that's what they are for.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```kotlin
val hash = generateSequence { createHash(longUrl) }
    .first { !shortUrlRepository.findById(it).isPresent }
```

... and of course, you can always localize `var` and pass it outside as `val`.

```kotlin
val someVal = run {
    var someVar: String = ""
    // do super logic with var
    someVar
}
...
```

Comment: ... and IMHO every kotlin newbie must read "concepts" and "standard library" here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/home.html .  You'll save a LOT of time this way.